# Using '*' as 'value at' operator in C

Tags: c, operators, variable-assignment

Here I have an issue in assigning values to a member of a structure, from a buffer that I am using to receive some data through UART.

The buffer that I have used is a char array/buffer, called buff, of size 35 bytes, and is a global buffer.
The 8th byte in the buffer is called left_low, which is a 4-byte value.
Now, as far I have understood C, operator '*' is the 'Value At' operator.
In order to copy 4 bytes starting from 8th byte of the buffer, following is the code that I have written.
Is this correct? Or do I need to use the memcpy() here? I dont know how memcpy()  would work in this case. Please Help!

```
char buff[35];
int write_function()  
{  
  struct calibration_data dcs2_config;  
  dcs2_config.left_low = *(buff+1*8); //will this work?  
  //or should this be done?  memcpy(&dcs2_config.left_low,buff+1*8,4);  

  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Note: `*(buff + 1*8)` or `*(buff + 8)` is just another way to write `buff[8]`; slightly less easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work.

The type of `buff+1*8` is `char*`, so the type of `*(buff+1*8)` is `char`. Therefore, `dcs2_config.left_low = *(buff+1*8);` will write the single-char value at `buff+1*8` into the 4-char `left_low` (doing integer promotion).

Your best bet is probably not to `memcpy` either, but to *cast* the pointer. Assuming `left_low` is an `int`:

```
dcs2_config.left_low = *((int *)(buff + 1*8));
```

Comment: or even `uint32_t` instead of `int` if there are really exactly 4 bytes to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only copy a char (one byte), because buff is a char array. The memcpy will work as expected.

I don't know why you write 1*8, when you can write 8, or sizeof(char)*8 (but remember that sizeof(char) is always 1).

Answer (score 0):

you should use memcpy.The way you are trying to copy will pick only one byte(char length).